# Free array pointed to by a pointer within a struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, struct

I have a stack implemented in dynamic array. Below are some of my functions. When I call stk_reset function, it seems that the stack is not freed completely.

Here is my struct. It is a requirement that I have to have a pointer inside struct pointing to the dynamic array

```
    typedef struct stack {
        char *items;
        int arrSize;
        int top;
    } StackStruct;


    void stack_create(StackStruct *s) {
        char *arr = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);

        if (arr == NULL) {
            printf("Insufficient memory to initialize stack.\n");
            return;
        }

        s->arrSize = 2;
        s->items = arr;
        s->top = -1;
    }
```

How do I deallocate each element of the array holding the stack? I used this statement free((s->items)++) with a for loop, but it did not work.

```
    void stk_reset(StackStruct *s) {
    int i;

        for (i = 0; i <= s->arrSize; i++)
            free((s->items)++);
        free(s->items);
        s->items = NULL;
        s->top = -1;
        s->arrSize = 0;
    }
```

Comment: You should learn what `malloc` and `free` do, practice using them on a simple example, and then revisit your design.

Comment: `free()` doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want one (1) call to `free` per call to `malloc`.  Here you've only allocated one item with room for two characters.  To `free` it, it's pretty straight-forward.  Here is what is called a "Safe" release (or free).

```
if (s->items != NULL) {
    free(s->items);
    s->items = NULL; // Reset to be safe.
}
```

Though to use this, you will need to make sure you *initialize* your value to NULL before you try to use it: `s->items = NULL;`.

No other `free` calls are required, and certainly not in a loop when you only had one `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only call `free` on the pointer returned to you by `malloc` and you can only free the whole block, not individual bytes.