# Deallocating a String object

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct

I am trying to write a function that is a memory-management tool, that will deallocate a `String` object and all its content, and this is what I have written so far but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone help in what I should be writing instead? I cannot use string.h also.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct _String {
   char     *data;     // dynamically-allocated array to hold the characters
   uint32_t  length;   // number of characters in the string
};
typedef struct _String String;   

/** Deallocates a String object and all its content.
*
* Pre:
* **str is a proper String object
* **str was allocated dynamically
* Post:
* (**str).data has been deallocated
* **str has been deallocated
* *str == NULL
*/
void String_Dispose(String** str) {
    free(**(str).length);
    str->length = 0; 
    **str.data == NULL; 
    //free(str);
     *str == NULL;    
}
```

A call to `String_Dispose()` would look something like this:

```
String *pStr = malloc( sizeof(String) );
. . .
// Initialize the String and use it until we're done with it.

. . .

String_Dispose(&pStr);
// At this point, every trace of the String object is gone and pStr == NULL.
```

The `String` object `String_Dispose()` is working on must have been allocated dynamically, because `String_Dispose()` will attempt to deallocate that object.

Comment: Is that all the code you have? If possible, please post a [mcve].

Comment: Postfix `.` has higher precedence than unary `*`.

Comment: Why this double dereferencing ??? Show the allocation code.

Comment: @RSahu yes this is all I have because I'm not sure how to go further with this. Any suggestions possibly?

Comment: Should that be `(**str).data`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. the allocation code? What do you mean? This is all that I was given and all I have written...

Comment: So what are you going to "deallocate" axactly?

Comment: @immibis It would explain the double dereferencing. But will raise questions about `str->length=0`.

Comment: @Leah Please edit the question with this information. It is unreadable as a comment.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The modification of the `length` member would effectively be a dead store *anyway*.

Comment: @Leah as you ask for suggestion, you can take a look to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743401/free-array-pointed-to-by-a-pointer-within-a-struct-in-c) which seems to achieve the same kind of things.

Comment: @EOF I just don't understand the intended usage and trying to deduce it from the semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Since the member access operator, `.`, binds tighter than the dereference operator, `*`, you need to use:

```
void String_Dispose(String** str) {
    free((**str).data);

    // No need for these lines since you are planning on setting *str to NULL.
    // (**str).length = 0; 
    // (**str).data = NULL;   // Use =, not ==

    free(*str);
    *str = NULL;          // Use =, not ==
}
```

Comment: I used this, but when I run my program it says "Aborted (core dumped)". Any ideas why?

Comment: As a wild guess based on your update: Because you are not allocating the `data` field.

Comment: @EugeneSh. does this mean I would then say malloc(sizeof(data)); ?

Comment: You don't want `sizeof(data)`, you want the length of the actual string.

Comment: @EugeneSh. how do you write that then?

Comment: You need a normal allocation code and usage example. Really, we can't just have chunks of information scattered across the comments.

Comment: @Leah, don't make this a consulting session. That's not the goal at SO. If you have further questions, post a new question with additional details.